# Event when user clicks Pick File?

Tags: iframe, onclick, filepicker.io

I'm using the basic 'Open Widget'

```
<input type="filepicker-dragdrop" id="jpeg_url" ....
```

Which works. However is there anyway to get some sort of notification when the user clicks the 'Pick file' button?

Background: The Pick File button is in an iframe of its own. Which is normally only 200px high. So the Filepicker.io box is rather unusable. The iframe is capable of controlling its own size, so when the user clicks the button - want to make the iframe bigger.

I guess could attach my own handler to the  that filepicker creates,

or even watch for the existance of the , but these seem like hacks.

(or could even just recreate the whole interface using the Pick Files and Drag-Drop Pane APIs, but the widget is simpler)

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way would be to apply a custom class to the widget via the `data-fp-button-class` property and then use a javascript library to listen to click events on the given class

Comment: How will know when the user closes the lightbox? Get the onchange on the <input> itself, but nothing if the user hits the 'X'.

Comment: That isn't part of the current API but will be in the next revision